# Erlang e Thrift

Tags: erlang, thrift

I want to make a Windows Service using Erlang and Thrift.

The service will have a single thread listening in a port (socket communication) and send request to a worker's thread. The Windows Service have to response quickily (milisencods) and the throughput is mandatory. (requests per second)
The workers thread will communicate each other. I think in Earlang to resolve this issue.

So i think erlang+thrift will work good. Am I right? Any  suggestions?

Comment: No idea on the Thrift question, but Erlang's [`gen_server`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html) would probably be a good starting point for your Erlang server needs.

Comment: I think Thrift will generate the code for the server. Am I wrong? I didnt know that Erlang have the function gen_server.

Comment: gen_server is not a function, it's part of OTP.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is reasonable. To bring you up to speed i would suggest reading up on gen_server, supervisor, application.
Thrift will generate stub files which by compiling will yield you a transport/acceptor. It's up to you to provide both the thrift api and the handler for this api.
Moreover be advised not to synchronize alot between processes if you need fast response times (ie. dont design your solution around synchronizing calls)

Comment: Só Thrift will only generate the stubs to client talk with server? I read in Thrift whitepaper that it creates a pool of worker thread too. But Erlang doesn't do that? Does gen_server create the worker thread pool too? Can i talk raw sockets independent of the language with a Erlang Server? thanks

Comment: Thrift will generate the 'protocol-code' of your API (from your .thrift file). It will not generate a pool per se - it will spawn a process every time someone connects to your server (ie. calls thrift_client:start).
You can always talk sockets, however protocol encoding is then up to you :)